# When was the footage from "The Hidden" shown in "The Time Traveler's Wife"?

Tags: the-time-travelers-wife

> The footage from "The Hidden" Courtesy of ...

> "Dark Victory" clip ...

These are words at the end of *The Time Traveler's Wife*. I could not recall the character's ever watching a movie/TV. I could not find nor by web-search neither in wiki when in the movie these other movie/clips were shown. Maybe somebody noticed?

The reason for curiosity I thought maybe some idea from clips is related to the film, like in *Logan* (2017) footage and idea from *The Shane* (1953).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Dark Victory](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031210/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)* is shown on the TV as Clare waits for Henry to return on their wedding night. Bette Davis is quite unmistakable.

[image: Screenshot of "The Time Travelor's Wife", showing a scene of Bette Davis in "Dark Victory"]

Several other shots of TVs are visible in the film. The scene from *The Hidden* occurs at 50 minutes 50s, when Clare and Henry are watching coverage of the lottery draw through the window of a TV shop. Although most of the TVs are showing the lottery, some are showing other channels. In particular one (circled in red) is showing the scene from a diner from *[The Hidden](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093185/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*. This is about 21 minutes into the film, when the alien is eating a meal while his boombox blares out at high volume, perturbing the other patrons such as the man with white hair shown in the image.

[image: Left: image from "The Time Traveler's Wife of the TV shop. Right: screen shot from "The Hidden", showing the diner scene.]

Comment: thanks. I am still slightly curious for what reason the Hidden was shown.

Comment: I had idea about TV shop, but only noted some western type movie on big screen. The Hidden was shown before they entered the shop! The makers noted in end credits "The Hidden", but not that western one.

Comment: Yes, the TV shop was showing a Western and also a film involving someone walking through a blizzard. Who knows what that could be! There was also a baseball game shown when Henry was having his MRI.

Answer (score 1):

From the "Connections" page on the [IMDb entry for *The Time Traveller's Wife*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0452694/movieconnections/?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn):

> ### Features
>
> *Dark Victory* (1939)
> On TV as she waits for him in bed.
>
> *The Hidden* (1987)
> Clip shown.

It doesn't mention where the *The Hidden* clip was shown in the film however.  The Connections page for *The Hidden* does show a large amount of referenced works, so it might be referenced as a kind of trope.